# md, mix disks and partitions in an array

Tags: partitioning, raid, disk, mdadm

My question is really how to mix in a 4 TB disk in my array consisting of 3 TB disks, which was partially answered here: [Can I create a hybrid software-RAID array with disks of different sizes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146244/can-i-create-a-hybrid-software-raid-array-with-disks-of-different-sizes)

Problem is, how do I mix partitions (a 3 TB partition of a 4 TB drive) with entire 3 TB disks? My current md consists of sdb, sdc, sdd, sde and sdf. No partitions as I just let mdadm use up and add the entire drive. How does sdg1 play along in the mix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
mdadm have no problem mixing entire disks and partitions given that the **partition type is set to 0xFD**. Using parted, this in non-intuitive since you need to create an ext2 partition and then use **set 1 raid on**, which will change the partition type.

Answer (score -1):

Be careful with hybrid mainboards. In this case here would not do e.g. dual-boot with proprietary operating systems. You could think about 2 swap-partitions or 4 swap-partitions (of course only one is used, but you have then spare partition for emergency-case). Assumed the hybrid mainboard has a hidden flash-rom (or flash-rom is writeable resp. flashable) on the rear side, then in case there is somehow 2 MB to 32 MB free on the partition-table, then the Linux-User could install an additional Linux-Distro, which fixes into flash-rom piece of mainboard, which is again better than a recovery-partition of proprietary system.

In case your mainboard is not hybrid (is then without efi or uefi ?!) you could divide partition in smaller logical partitions after backup. You have not posted the partition table of your concerning question ?!

Comment: The mainboard isn't hybrid and I'm not booting from the array nor the spare space of the 4 TB disk.

Comment: No hybrid, no EFI/UFI, no swap partitions, no flash-ROM, no recovery partitions. You are focusing on system-boot issues which is not relevant for my question. How does mdadm handle a mixture of entire disks, i.e. sdf and partitions, i.e. sdg1, on the same array?

Comment: @winny - be more precise with, what system version you use and in case it is an elder Ubuntu version then unix/linux is normally coping with 2 TB partition (in Kernel 2.6), but you are questioning about how "to mix" partitions ? What do you mean with "mixing" ? You want to merge files of different partitions together or what ? That is no sense somehow in your question ... so you want to partition a client and the server is outside of this client ? . . . then you should know more about logical partitions. When only few partitions are too big then the installation is working much slowlier.

Comment: 3.16. No 2 TB partition issues. mdadm can build an array from entire disks like in my array [sdc, sdd, sde and so on] or from partitions [sdb1 sdc1 sdd1 and so on] on disks like in many examples on the internet, or any block device for that matter. How can I mix the two, both partitions and entire disks?

Comment: @winny - it is some more work, but it is worth this. Set-up logical partitions for to backup each partition (directory) like /etc, /opt and /bin and so on ... then after this you could merge files together for "mixing" them.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you really don't understand. ALL system related issues, boot, UEFI, recovery partitions, 2 TB limits, system folders like /etc or anything similar has no connection to my md. No system files are there, nothing is booted from there.